# How to get data from MS SQL Server 2008 into Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, linux, sql-server

I need to create some layers in my map from a Microsoft SQL 2008 database.  I am using Openlayers and Mapserver.  The Mapserver instance is running on SUSE linux, so the Mapserver documentation on MSSQL that discusses the plugin for Windows is not very helpful.
I know it is possible because I have in the past gotten it to work, however I scrapped that project in favor for something else.  I now have a need for it once again and have been unsuccessful finding any clear and concise examples.
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the Windows plugin you are referring to is the MSSQL Plugin at http://mapserver.org/input/vector/mssql.html?

Does the OGR driver work on Linux when connecting to Linux? http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mssqlspatial.html

It makes reference to a different ODBC driver that can be used in the connection string:

> The connection may contain the optional Driver parameter if a custom
>   SQL server driver should be loaded (like FreeTDS). The default is {SQL
>   Server}

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) is

> a set of libraries for Unix and Linux that allows your
>   programs to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase
>   databases.

So maybe this driver can also work with the MapServer SQL Server 2008 plugin? If not you could try creating an [OGR Layer](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html).